# Using AWS Parameter Store value in Filebeat configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2, filebeat

I want to use Parameter Store(or secret manager) values in my filebeat.yml
(EC2 SUSE Linux).
The reason i want to do this is, that when my elastic password changes, i don't want to have to edit 50+ yml files

if i use:

> ws ssm get-parameter --name my_stored_value --query 'Parameter.Value' --output text

then i am succesfully grabbing the value

The problem I'm running into is how to access this variable in the filebeat.yml.

I have tried setting it to an enviroment variable called

> parameter

when i run

> echo ${parameter} on my ec2 instance

it shows the correct value

However, when I change the hardcoded value of the config to this:

> name: ${parameter}

then i get errors that the field isn't set

Does anyone know how i can succesfully grab a value from my parameter store and us it in my yml?

Comment: Please elaborate on how you are "setting it to an environment variable" and on how you are running the Filebeat process (like is it via systemd?).

Comment: eventually i want to grab the var from secret manager or param store, but for now i just set it manually.

im just running filebeat with the filebeat run command